# SCCM2012 .MSI Installation

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation, ms-office, sccm

i have a problem with during application installation to client. My application is Microsoft office add-in. And then i try to deploy this application to the client i don't see this files on client side but software centre says that application was successfully installed.

Why it happen? I try to install another applications for example 7Zip.MSI, my own application .msi and anothers, all ok, but if i try to install Microsoft office add-in  the files are somewhere disappeared. for script execute i used this command:

```
msiexec /i "WToysSetup.msi" /qb
```

i have already installed microsoft word on clients machine.

Comment: Do you have a log file for this install? In not, please try to create one with ``msiexec.exe /i "WToysSetup.msi" /L*V "C:\msilog.log"  /qn`` (``/qb`` means basic UI- ``/qn`` is totally silent install).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I understand why the add-ins does not start, because .msi can not whrite information in registry!! The i istall manually the files appear in registry and it help the add-in to find the path to installed files and add-ins starts automatically then office is run. I tryed to install only file.reg via sccm after install the add-in , but i don’t know how can i make it executable, because the problem is same “the .msi don’t write files to register and if i run the script by: regedit.exe /s file.reg” maybe you know please how can i install the .msi or execute only .reg file?? Please

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible issues here. I'm assuming you're using a Visual Studio setup project in the absence of a specific tool being mentioned.

1. The install requires elevation, but in a silent install Windows won't show the UAC elevation dialog, and it will run without elevation. Most installs like this would fail, but you might find that a Visual Studio generated MSI reverted to a Just me install, and installed the files to an unexpected location (often C:\ and not Program Files).
2. MSIs can be published or assigned with SCCM-type deployments, one is to the system the other to the user, and that's Everyone or Just me again, so it may have done a per user install because of that.
3. Regardless of whether it seems to have worked, if it requires elevation and fails then it may just fail silently, which would be one reason you can't find the files. You should be able to see in Programs&Features/Apps whether it is actually installed, but it was installed as a per user/Just me install you'd need to log on as that user to see it in the list of installed apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, PhilDW! I've found a way to install the files to see , but the problem is still the same, when running the Word, the plugin does not appear, which was installed via sccm, when it's set to manually in client computer it works and the plugin in the Word can see what the problem might be?